# Impedance-critical diff-pair routing

Tags: impedance, pcie

I need to route PCIe RX and TX diffpairs:

[image]

I can't change the bottom connector (fits into M.2 KeyE socket), neither the top (M.2 KeyM socket).

Normally, how shall I wire these diffpairs?

It seems I have two options:

1. Use via-s (absolutely not recommended for impedance-critical routes)
2. hack the connector and remove some of its SMD pins, and wire one pair under those pins

There is a slightly different, but tightly coupled question here with this impedance [calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-stripline-impedance/): "stripline differential impedance":

[image]

Stripline here seems to be placed in some inside layer (i.e. not TOP and not BOTTOM).

How is the signal gets into middle layer? It must be routed with a via from TOP/BOTTOM.

Then via will ruin the whole calculation, isn't it?

Comment: looks like you'll have to use vias!

Comment: We use properly designed via structures all the time in RF/microwave applications up to 35 GHz (my personal experience).

Answer (score 4):

Vias are certainly not recommended *if possible* with PCle routing. However, if imperative you *can* route these lines using vias as long as you adhere to the best practices surrounding them. Using vias will not ruin the whole calculation as long as you do your research as to how to correctly integrate them (for example, include ground vias nearby).

Your second question has two possible answers: 1) the signal begins on an outer layer and is routed to an inner layer using a via or 2) the PCle connector is a through-hole component, so the signal is initially routed from the connector using an inner layer.

Answer (score 3):

Every track that isn't a short, straight line, on one single layer - these are all deviations from the ideal and to some extent undesirable but usually manageable. For your design, option 2) every time, you'll get better results with vias than hacking the PCB apart. For this design, I'd loop the tracks over, then put the vias in to get past the cross over. This child-like drawing should make it clear.[image]

I can just see a bit of trace-length matching, so you clearly know to do this.

Plenty of tools like the PCB Toolkit from SaturnPCB will calculate the impedance of a via for you, and it's just a case of tuning the via so it matches the impedance of your circuit, it's not a definite "this will ruin my impedance". Something like this
[image: ![enter image description here]
Of course, it's undesirable, but not fatal. I'd be keen also to know the frequency/bandwidth you're using for this, as this matters.

For your second part, the buried strip line, the word you're probably looking for is a blind via. That's a via that goes from an outer layer to an inner layer, but not all the way through the PCB and hence avoiding the stub.

Comment: Frequency is 5GHz. For your drawing, thx. You need two more, no? to get back those lines on the TOP plane?

Comment: You are showing a single ended via, even if the calculator supports differential vias for differential signals. Also, the frequency is not 5 GHz, the bit rate for square-wavy bits is 5 Gbps, which means, sinusoidal frequencies of at least up to 5th harmonic or 25 GHz must pass relatively unaltered.

Comment: @LordTeddy once you've looped the traces up and around, why did you also add in vias? Isn't the point that you need to do one or the other? I don't see what purpose the vias serve in your proposal. Also kudos for the SaturnPCB Toolkit suggestion, very helpful tool.

Comment: @Daniel oops, yes you need two sets of vias, one to get to the other plane, one to get back

Comment: @InBedded16, I missed a set of vias. One gets you to the bottom layer so you can go under the pads, and another to get back to the right layer. A loop like that swaps the tracks around as well, in a softer way than if done in a straight line

Comment: @LordTeddy ah okay that new drawing makes more sense.

Comment: Via spacing: 3mm: those vias are at least 5mm distance from each other, can you please update the screenshot?

Comment: A) The drawing is just supposed to be indicative B) you'll want to fuss with the via parameters to suit your application